# List as index in matlab

Tags: python, matlab

There is this method written in `Matlab` that I want to translate into `Python`. However, I don't understand how to interpret the notation of indexing the sparse matrix `M` with a row of the matrix `faces`. What would be the equivalent in `Python`?

```
M = spalloc(size(template,1), size(template,1), 10*size(template,1));

for i = 1:size(faces,1)
    v = faces(i,:); % faces is a Nx3 matrix
    ...

    M(v, v) = M(v, v) + WIJ; % WIJ is some 3x3 matrix
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Eric Yu` uses a dense numpy array:

```
In [239]: A=np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]])                              
In [240]: A                                                                  
Out[240]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [5, 6, 7]])
In [241]: v=[0,1]
```

this indexing selects rows:

```
In [242]: A[v]                                                               
Out[242]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

and from that select columns:

```
In [243]: A[v][:,v]                                                          
Out[243]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

But `A[v]` is a copy, not a view, so assignment will fail:

```
In [244]: A[v][:,v] = 0                                                      
In [245]: A                                                                  
Out[245]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

===

To properly index a block of a numpy array, use `ix_` (or equivalent) to create indexing arrays that broadcast against each other to define the block:

```
In [247]: np.ix_(v,v)                                                        
Out[247]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]), array([[0, 1]]))
In [248]: A[np.ix_(v,v)]                                                     
Out[248]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [249]: A[np.ix_(v,v)]=0                                                   
In [250]: A                                                                  
Out[250]: 
array([[0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 5],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

Without the `ix_` transform, indexing with `[v,v]` selects a diagonal:

```
In [251]: A[v,v]                                                             
Out[251]: array([0, 0])
```

MATLAB `M(v,v)` indexes the block.  Indexing the diagonal on the other hand requires use of `sub2idx` (or something like that).  This is a case where MATLAB's indexing notation makes one task easy, and the other more complex.  `numpy` does the reverse.

===

What I wrote is applicable to sparse matrices as well

```
In [253]: M=sparse.lil_matrix(np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]))           
In [254]: M                                                                  
Out[254]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

The diagonal selection:

```
In [255]: M[v,v]                                                             
Out[255]: 
<1x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [256]: _.A                                                                
Out[256]: array([[1, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

Note that this matrix is (1,2), still 2d, in the style of MATLAB matrices.

block selection:

```
In [258]: M[np.ix_(v,v)]                                                     
Out[258]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [259]: _.A                                                                
Out[259]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=int64)
In [260]: M[np.ix_(v,v)]=0                                                   
In [261]: M.A                                                                
Out[261]: 
array([[0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 5],
       [5, 6, 7]], dtype=int64)
```

`sparse.csr_matrix` will index in the same way (with some differences in the assignment step).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
A=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]]
M=np.array(A)
v=[0,1]
M[v][:,v]
```

the result is:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: Your test `M` is numpy `ndarray`, not a sparse matrix.  This approach will fail when used in assignment.