# Why do I get a Memory Error when solving a sparse system of linear equations?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

When trying to solve the large, sparse system of linear equations from below, I simply get a `MemoryError:`. How can I resolve this issue?

Also, this code is based on an implementation in Matlab which should run fine. In the original version, `M` is a three-dimensional matrix, I don't know whether the memory issues maybe occur because of my modification transforming `M` to a 2D `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` (instead of `coo`) s.t. I can iteratively fill `M` in.

```
def dectrans(features, faces, template):
    """
    Decode transformation matrix.

    features : shape (3*N) numpy.ndarray
    faces : (Nx3) array
    template : (Nx3) array
    """
    ftrs = features

    weight = 1

    fixvertex = 1
    fixto = np.zeros((3))

    # M shape originally (len(template), len(template), 10 * len(template))
    M = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(template)+fixvertex, len(template) * 10 * len(template)))
    dx = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((len(template)+fixvertex,3))

    # build laplacian system
    for i in range(len(faces)):
        v = faces[i,:]
        ...
        M[v][:,v] = M[v][:,v] + WIJ # WIJ some 3x3 matrix
        dx[v,:] = dx[v,:] + WIJ.dot(x.T)

    weight = np.ones((fixvertex)) * weight

    for i in range(fixvertex):
        M[len(template)+i, fixvertex-1] = weight[i]

    dx[len(template):len(template),:] = fixto.dot(np.tile(weight, (3))) 

    M = np.real(M)
    dx = np.real(dx)
    Mt = M.T
    model = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(Mt @ M, Mt.dot(dx)) # here I get the error

    return model
```

This is the traceback of the error that I got:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9aa6e73eb179> in <module>
     20         rr = encrelrot(v_positions, faces, r_v_positions, f_neighbors)
     21 
---> 22         modelout = dectrans(decrelrot(rr, f_neighbors), faces, r_v_positions)

<ipython-input-8-cdb51dd3cadf> in dectrans(features, faces, template)
    616     print("Size dx", dx.nnz)
    617     #M = M.tocsr()
--> 618     model = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(Mt @ M, Mt.dot(dx))
    619 
    620     return model

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __matmul__(self, other)
    560             raise ValueError("Scalar operands are not allowed, "
    561                              "use '*' instead")
--> 562         return self.__mul__(other)
    563 
    564     def __rmatmul__(self, other):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    480             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    481                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 482             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    483 
    484         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    494                                      other.indptr, other.indices),
    495                                     maxval=M*N)
--> 496         indptr = np.empty(major_axis + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
    497 
    498         fn = getattr(_sparsetools, self.format + '_matmat_pass1')

MemoryError:
```

Comment: Could you print the size of `Mt`, `M` and `dx` and relate them to your RAM size ?
You can try to process `Mt @ M` and `Mt.dot(dx)` before the line generating the error.

Also, [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) can help you track the error

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion. `sys.getsizeof(M)` as well for `dx` returns 56 bytes. I have 521MB free RAM. Apparently processing `Mt @ M` results in this error.

Comment: And how about the size of `Mt` ?

Comment: `Mt` has the same size of 56 bytes. Do you think running the code on another computer with more free memory might resolve this issue?

Comment: no, these are very small matrices (sorry, I didn't notice `Mt` was just `M` transposed...). 
Try, on the line before the one generating an error, computing `MtM = Mt.matmul(M)` and also `MtDx = Mt.dot(dx)` and rewrite `model = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(MtM, MtDx)` to see if you have a different error.

Comment: also, print the shapes of `M` and `dx` (with `print(M.shape, dx.shape)`)

Comment: `shape M and dx : (6891, 474721000), (6891, 3)` and `Mt.dot(dx)` returns `MemoryError: std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: Don't use `M[v][:,v]` style of indexing with sparse matrices (best not even use it with numpy arrays either).  `Mt.dot(dx)` is producing the memory error because the result is a large dense array - something that is no longer taking advantage of the memory savings of a sparse matrix.

Comment: `getsizeof` is useless for determining the size of a sparse matrix.  It does work for dense ones, but `shape` is generally more useful.

Comment: `M.nnz` is the best measure of the memory use of sparse matrix.

Comment: I got this style of indexing from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209095/list-as-index-in-matlab/56209207#56209207). How can I circumvent this indexing problem as well as the memory overflow? What I'm actually trying to do is to translate a Matlab code into Python and I don't really know which sparse matrices to use.

Comment: The answer to your previous question applies to a numpy array (`np.array...`). and does not try to do assignment.  I should probably add my preferred answer.

Comment: Oh okay, and that would be great! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback should show whether the problem is in the `spsolve` or while creating one or both of the arguments, `Mt@M` or `Mt.dot(dx)`.

With `M` and `dx` shapes `((6891, 474721000)`, `(6891, 3)`

```
 Mt@M
 (474721000,6891) + (6891, 474721000) => (474721000, 474721000)
 Mt.dot(dx)   # why not Mt@dx?
 (474721000,6891) + (6891, 3) => (474721000, 3)
```

Depending on the structure of nonzeros in these, it's possible the @ product has many more nonzeros than `M`, and that could produce the memory error.  The traceback for one or the other might help us diagnose this.

More commonly memory errors result from trying to create a dense array from a sparse one, but that does seem to be the case here. But again, the traceback could help rule that out.

`lil` format is the recommended one if filling matrix values incrementally.  `csr` is used for matrix products, but `sparse` readily converts `lil` to `csr` if needed.  So that shouldn't be an issue.

===

Create a sparse matrix with 1 nonzero element:

```
In [263]: M=sparse.lil_matrix((1000,100000))                                 
In [264]: M                                                                  
Out[264]: 
<1000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [265]: M[0,0]=1                                                           
In [266]: M                                                                  
Out[266]: 
<1000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

This `@` did not produce a memory error, and the result has only 1 nonzero term, as expected.  But there was a noticeable delay in running this, suggesting it is doing some large calculation:

```
In [267]: M.T@M                                                              
Out[267]: 
<100000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Doing the same `@` on the `csr` equivalent does not have that time delay:

```
In [268]: M1=M.tocsr()                                                       
In [269]: M1.T@M1                                                            
Out[269]: 
<100000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

===

You mention 3d sparse matrices in MATLAB.  You must be using some sort of 3rd party extension or work around, since MATLAB sparse is limited to 2d (at least it was when I used it years ago for FEM work).

The `scipy.sparse` `csc` format is similar to MATLAB's internal sparse.  In fact that's what you'll get if you transfer a matrix via `save` and `scipy.io.loadmat`.  `csr` is similar but with a row orientation.

When I created FEM stiffness matrices in MATLAB I used the equivalent of the `scipy` `coo` inputs.  That is, creating 3 arrays of `data`, `row`, and `col`.  When a `coo` is converted to `csr`, duplicate elements are added, neatly handling the submatrix overlap of FEM elements.  (this behavior is the same in `scipy` and MATLAB).

Repeatedly adding the `lil` matrices as you do should work (if indexing is right), but I expect it will be substantially slower.

Comment: The traceback tells me that the `@` causes this issue. How can I see the number of nonzero entries? And oddly enough, `M.nnz` returns 1.

Comment: I think the `M[v][:,v]=` is failing, for reasons I explain in the other question.  So you are only setting the `fixvertex` element.  So `M.nnz` of 1 makes sense.  I'd have to see the traceback to say anything more about the memory error.

Comment: Okay, I pasted the traceback into my original question. I'm gonna look at your answer to my other question now, thank you for taking your time!

Comment: According to the traceback the error is in the `Mt@M` (matmul) calculation, when it tries to initial the `indptr` array for the result matrix (`csr` format): `np.empty(474721001, np.int64)`.  That by itself shouldn't cause a memory error.  I'm guessing it's a cumulative memory use problem - too many large arrays.

Comment: Oh, so there's probably no simple way to fix this? Maybe I need to rewrite this then. Thank you :)